# Block HTTP POST request

Tags: php, http, .htaccess

I am seeing an usually high number of HTTP POST requests on my website, and I was wondering: Is there any way to block a POST request on a particular php page by making modifications to either the php file or .htaccess file? Thanks in advance!

Comment: is it posting from your form? if it is put a reCaptcha on it

Comment: I think that using PHP is impossible to block them. Just an idea: use iptables filter rules http://www.webhostingtalk.com/showthread.php?t=856469

Comment: on any particular page you an check if $_POST is populated and return a 404 header if it is, that may reduce the number. but generally i would ignore it, all sites get a lot of 'rubbish' traffic

Comment: We are talking about thousands and thousands of POST requests. It's not a form, the traffic is on the home page.

Comment: from one ore more ip addresses? you may be able to trace to source and deal with it directly

Comment: Not sure how I would go about finding out about the IP addresses.

Comment: easy fix: put latest posts (say 10), in file (serialized array), save timestamp and IP. On post-request, read and shift ip+TS into file. If file contains 10 posts from same ip, and within say 1min, you've got an attacker... Start with $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']...

Comment: Apache access logs or add some php, how do you know there are theses mystery posts with out seeing them in the access logs?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In native PHP it's as simple as checking one [`$_SERVER`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php) variable:

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    die('Post is not allowed');
}
```

Within `.htaccess`, use a combination of [`<Files>`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#filesmatch) and [`<limit>`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#limit):

```
<Files myfile.php>
    <Limit POST> 
        Order deny,allow 
        Deny from all 
    </Limit>
</files>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'll try this out, and hopefully it'll work!

Comment: The PHP doesn't seem to be capturing the POST request for some reason. It may be useful to point out that I am using WordPress.

Answer (score 2):

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']) == 'POST') die();
```

Answer (score 0):

POST /test HTTP/1.1
Host: foo.example
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: 27

field1=value1&field2=value2

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).